# I need to copy formulae and formatting from the row above or the row below into a newly inserted row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook, containing a separate worksheet for each member of my Barbershop Chapter, that keeps track of each member's ad sales. Worksheet 1 summarizes data from each member worksheet. When we get a new member, I manually copy a master member worksheet, insert it alphabetically into the list of member worksheets and rename it with the member's name. I have a macro that inserts this new member/worksheet name into a column range in worksheet 1 that contains a list of members/worksheets and then sorts this list alphabetically. This works well. Now, and this is where I am having problems, I would like to insert code in this same macro (if this is the proper way to do it) to copy formulae and formatting (from the row above if the new row is in the midst of the list, or from the row below if the new worksheet happens to get inserted at the top of the member list), column 2 through the end of the row, down into the new row. I could do all of this manually, but I am trying to learn to write macros. I could record a macro based on doing the task manually, but that wouldn't give me the code to allow for inserting new columns within the range containing the formulae, would it?  Below is my incomplete code (I'm not pleased at how it copied); the If statement is where I'm trying to check to see if the new row is at the top of the member list or in the middle and accomplish the copy. Please don't laugh at my novice efforts;-) Thanks for your help.

```
 Public Sub AddWkshtNametoGrandTotals()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim WsName As String
    Dim Ws_GT As Worksheet
    Dim MemberList As Range
    Dim NewNameRef As Range

    Set Ws_GT = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Ws_GT.Range("A:A").Name = "MemberList"
    'Find first empty cell at bottom of worksheet Grand Totals
    LastRow = Ws_GT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    WsName = ActiveSheet.Name 'Keep track of current worksheet
    Ws_GT.Cells(LastRow, 1) = WsName  'Put current worksheet name
    'into first empty cell at bottom of worksheet Grand Totals
    Range("MemberList").Sort Key1:=Range("MemberList") 'Sort member name list with new name added
    Set NewNameRef = Ws_GT.Range("MemberList").Find(WsName).Cells
    'Check for position of new row
    If NewNameRef.Row = 1 Then
        Range("NewNameRef.Offset(1, 1),Cells(Columns.Count,1).End.xlRight.Column").Copy _
        Destination:=Range("NewNameRef.Offset(0, 1)")
        'NewNameRef.Offset(-1, 1).Copy.EntireRow
        'NewNameRef.Offset(0, 1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        'NewNameRef.Offset(0, 1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
    Else
        Rows(Selection.Row - 1).Copy
        Rows(Selection.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown

    End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Always helps to show your existing code (or at least the relevant parts)

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to copy the formats and formulas *before* sorting:

**EDIT** - after seeing your workbook

```
Public Sub AddWkshtNametoSheet1()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim WsName As String
    Dim WsGT As Worksheet
    Dim MemberList As Range

    Set WsGT = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Grand Totals")

    WsName = ActiveSheet.Name 'Keep track of current worksheet

    'Find first empty cell at bottom of Column 1, Sheet1

    With WsGT
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
        WsGT.Range("A8:A" & LastRow).Name = "MemberList"
        .Rows(LastRow - 1).Copy
        .Cells(LastRow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .Cells(LastRow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
        .Cells(LastRow, 1) = WsName
    End With

    Range("MemberList").Sort Key1:=Range("MemberList")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim, but when I inserted this code into my workbook as a separate module, the line "Set Ws_GT = Sheets("Sheet1")" gives me a  "Runtime Error 9, Subscript Out of Range" error. Did I insert it in the wrong place?

Comment: That error indicates there's no sheet with that name  - check your workbook.

Comment: There is a worksheet, "Sheet1". This is the worksheet where all the data from the member worksheets is totaled and summarized.

Comment: Then try qualifying that with a workbook reference: eg `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")`  This is always a good thing to do in any case.

Comment: I added the "ThisWorkbook" qualifier and still get the same error. When I hit Debug, "Set WsGT = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")" is highlighted in yellow; this is the source of the error, correct? (I removed the underscore from the variable thinking that perhaps this may be the source of the error. I have no idea how to troubleshoot this problem>

Comment: I have a backup of this workbook; I injected this code into it and I get the same error there also.

Comment: Does the placement of the code matter? I have placed the code in its own module and in "ThisWorkbook" object and still get the same error.

Comment: The code should go in a regular module, and I'm assuming the code is in the same workbook as the sheets you're working with. If you like you can share a copy (or a stripped-down version) and I will take a look. DropBox or something similar would work for sharing.

Comment: OK, I've uploaded the workbook to DropBox, now how do I share that with you?

Comment: Tim, just checking to see if you were able to download the spreadsheet.

Comment: Did you check my edit to my answer?  I made that after seeing your file.

Comment: I thought it prudent to use "Sheet1" instead of "Grand Totals" in case someone (perhaps I, myself) decided to change the name of that sheet. Assuming that line was the problem, can you, briefly, tell me why using "Sheet1" didn't work?  I thought using "Sheet#" and "Sheet Name" were interchangeable.

Comment: If you mean `Sheet1` is the code name of the sheet as seen in the VB editor (vs. the "name" of the sheet in the sheet tab) then yes, that's a better thing to do, but you don't use it like you did in your question: `Set Ws_GT = Sheets("Sheet1")` but like this : `Set Ws_GT = Sheet1`

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I do appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a table (Ribbon / Insert / Table) in Excel >2003 a new table row in the table will be created automatically if you add something in the row right below the last one in the table. The formulae will apply automatically as well.

```
Sub M_snb()
  With ListObjects(1).Range
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(1).Value = "new"
    .Columns(1).Sort .Cells(1), , , , , , , xlYes
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim - just checking to see if you were able to download the spreadsheet.

Comment: Not at all. Where can I find a link to that file ?